# how to passed array in product_form to observer in magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

my phtml file code (below input tag is in for loop i=0 to i<5)

```
       <input type="text" name="array[]" value="<? echo $i ;?>" data-form-part='product_form'>
```

observer code

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

```
    $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
    
    $post = $this->_request->getPostValue();
    
    var_dump($post['array']);die();
    
    
}
```

after save product only print last value of array[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange!

Give the key to the array when iterates.

```
<input type="text" name="array[<? echo $i ;?>]" value="<? echo $i ;?>" data-form-part='product_form'>
```

Otherwise it will take only the last element of the array, keys are overwriting with empty in each iteration.